# How could I decode a JWT token in Paw

Tags: decode, jwt, paw-app, json-web-token

I found an extension for generating JWT in Paw, but nothing so far about decoding the tokens and using the payload as dynamic vars.

Comment: Nothing yet. We haven't done custom data visualizers yet, but it's something we'd like to add in the future. What would be the use case for you? Decode a JWT received for display/debug purposes?

Comment: The purpose would be to decode the received JWT payload, and then use some of those values in further requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use our JWT Decode extension: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/?extension_type=dynamic_value&q=jwt

- Insert it in the field where you need the decoded value
- Paste your JWT in the input filed or extract JWT from a previous response/request with a dynamic value (see screenshot)
- Filter the value out of payload by keypath

[image: input]
[image: filtering]